# Setting value to flashvars property doesn't work

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shockwave

I'm trying to set value to the property FlashVars when inserting shockwave flash movie  to PowerPoint 2010 using vba like this:

```
Dim s As Shape
Set s = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddOLEObject(0, 0, -1, -1, ClassName:="ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash")

With s.OLEFormat.Object
    .FlashVars = "parm1 = val1"
    .EmbedMovie = True
    .Movie = "D:\Samples\test.swf"
End With
```

However, after executing the setting command (s.OLEFormat.Object.FlashVars = "parm1 = val1" ),  the value of FlashVars remains empty. Do you have any idea about this weird behavior ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about embedding Flash in this fashion, but in the browser an alternative to defining a FlashVars object can be to append the variables to the SWF file name.  That might be worth a try if a proper solution does not present itself.

```
.Movie = "D:\Samples\test.swf?parm1=var1"
```